# Reload data calling all cells which are not visible in view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have an array with group of 100 items ,while i'm doing reload data total 100 cells are reloading.in this case each cell having images get download at a time then it showing memory warning.but i need to reload data for visible items on screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronously Loading TableView Images via NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787681/asynchronously-loading-tableview-images-via-nsurlconnection)

Comment: after reload data of collection view it is calling view for cell at index for 100 times but normally it has to call 10 times or 5 according o cell visibility. but for me this is new issue

Comment: You probably want to include some code with your question. Here's a framework that can help you load stuff asynchronously. https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: i have use that but same isue

Comment: if we do reload data how many cells could reload?

Comment: Show the code you are using otherwise everything said is just guess work and opinion.

Comment: will display cell calling at a time for all 100 cells, when i scroll it then it wont scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [IndexPath](), with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```